# Apply offset to scaling to preserve a specific point

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scaling

I am currently struggling with a WPF canvas and scaling. I want to be able to scale the canvas around a specific point (the given point should stay at the same screen position after scaling).

The scaling is done with a simple **ScaleTransform**. The Translation is stored in a **Point** object and is applied to all shapes in the canvas. That means that I have to offset all shapes (modify the Translation Point) after the scaling was applied. For the sake of simplicity, here a simplified code

```
class CanvasManager
{
    Point mTranslation; // holds the translation
    Canvas mCanvas;
    ScaleTransform mCanvasScale; // linked to mCanvas

    // Constructor omitted

    public void Scale(double factor, Point pt)
    {
        // retrieve the previous scaling factor
        double oldfactor = mCanvasScale.ScaleX;
        //apply the new factor
        mCanvasScale.ScaleX = factor;
        mCanvasScale.ScaleY = factor;
        // now offset so Point pt gets back at its original position
        mTranslation.X += ???;
        mTranslation.Y += ???;
    }
}
```

Point **pt** is coming from the mouse event measured relative to the canvas and includes the scaling. (When the Scale is 2 then a relative screen x-coordinate of 200 gives me 400 as the value for **pt**)
The Transform (Scale) is applied with the following code snippet:

```
mCanvasScale = new ScaleTransform();
mCanvas.LayoutTransform = mCanvasScale;
```

How do I get my correct offset for mTranslation?

Best regards
Dennis

Comment: You should be able to scale around a specific point by just setting the ScaleTransform's `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties.

Comment: @Clemens I tried that but it did not seem to have an effect on the scaling. In the Creation and in the Resize event I had something like mCanvasScale.CenterX = mCanvas.Width/2;

Comment: How do you apply the Transform to the Canvas?

Comment: @Clemens Edited original post. I am using the LayoutTransform Property

Comment: Try RenderTransform instead. LayoutTransform ignores any translations.

Comment: @Clemens This seems to scale the whole control, but I only want to scale the elements inside, so I can have a fixed "view" which can be moved and scaled. Everything works so far, but I can only scale from (0/0) to the right & down

Comment: Yes of course this scales the whole control, as you apply the transform to the control. In order to scale only the child elements, you would have to apply the transform to each of them. There is however no visual difference unless the Canvas has a Background brush.

Comment: @Clemens I know that Translations do not work, thats why I shift my elements with my custom offset. I do not want to use any Scroll* Objects. It should be simple to calculate the offset, but I just cant wrap my head around this :P (The canvas has a background brush and it scales over other elements in the form when I use RenderTransform)

Answer (score 1):

The solution should be

```
class CanvasManager
{
    Point mTranslation; // holds the translation
    Canvas mCanvas;
    ScaleTransform mCanvasScale; // linked to mCanvas

    // Constructor omitted

    public void Scale(double factor, Point pt)
    {
        // retrieve the previous scaling factor
        double oldfactor = mCanvasScale.ScaleX;
        //apply the new factor
        mCanvasScale.ScaleX = factor;
        mCanvasScale.ScaleY = factor;
        // now offset so Point pt gets back at its original position
        mTranslation.X -= ( (pt.X * factor) - (pt.X * oldfactor) ) / factor;
        mTranslation.Y -= ( (pt.Y * factor) - (pt.Y * oldfactor) ) / factor;
    }
}
```